# Frequencies emitted when electron falls back to lower energy state

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, photoelectric-effect

Does an excited electron fall straight back to ground state like a quantum jump or does it go through the intermediate states which would result in different frequencies of photons being emitted lets take photoexcitation as an example.

Why does the incident photon have to have energy exactly equal to difference of the energies of two desired states in photoexcitation which not the case in excitation by electron .The excess energy is k.e. for the deflected electron.